# Error when linking Access to SharePoint library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, microsoft-access

I wondered if anyone might be able to help with this problem that we have been trying to solve for a couple of weeks.

I have a Microsoft Access database which is linked to three form libraries in SharePoint. I now want to link to a fourth library and I am getting the following message:

> The Microsoft Access database engine encountered an error while communicating with SharePoint. More detailed information: 'The query cannot be completed because the number of lookup columns it contains exceeds the lookup column threshold enforced by the administrator'

There are no lookup columns in this library. 
I have SharePoint 2010 and I was using Office 2010 (and InfoPath 2010) and IE7.
My IT dept has upgraded me to Office 2013 now and IE10 (64 bit) but I still get the same message.

I have tried to link to a brand new database and its the same message and I have also tried to link to SharePoint from Access and the other way around from SharePoint selecting the task pane and 'track this list in Access' from a datasheet view and it doesn't seem to make a difference.
I've also tried using Firefox browser.
My PC has also been completely rebuilt and my profile cleared.

I have Full Control permissions to the site I'm trying to link to.
The SharePoint administrator in my IT dept is able to link to this library on his PC but not on my PC but we now both have the same software installed. Might this be permission related? But I can still link to the other three libraries I have which are in the same site

Has anyone encountered this before or have any idea what it might be? I cannot see any difference between this library and the three which I can link to.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say I ever bumped into this but here are some thoughts:

- your details point out the obvious: there is a lookup threshold limit and you are forbidden from exceeding it
- the fact that the admin can do what you cannot only serves as further argument to the previous point. as he is admin, he is likely to be able to ignore the threshold with his account
- in msdn's article [list view lookup threshold uncovered](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spses/archive/2013/12/02/sharepoint-2010-2013-list-view-lookup-threshold-uncovered.aspx), it clearly states

> What classifies as Lookup columns: Standard lookup columns,
>   single-value managed metadata, multiple-value managed metadata,
>   single-value people and group columns, and multiple-value people and
>   group columns , Workflow Status , Created by , Modified by ( people )
>   are obviously counted as lookup columns .

[here is a similar post](http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/148/t/229372.aspx)

hope this helps.

good luck